# Covariance of correlated lognormal random variables.

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, normal-distribution, moment-generating-functions

Suppose $X_1,X_2,...,X_N$ are correlated lognormal random variables  such that $$cov(\ln X_i,\ln X_j)=c_{ij}$$

and $\ln  X_i\sim N(\mu_i,\sigma_i^2)$.

Is there a way to find $cov(X_i,X_j) $ with only the provided information?

Comment: Here is the answer, for each couple $(X_i, X_j)$
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/132855/expectation-variance-and-correlation-of-a-bivariate-lognormal-distribution

Comment: @NN2: OP never said that the variables $\ln X_i$ are multivariate normally distributed. You are making an extra assumption there that indeed renders the problem solvable. But the general problem without that assumption is not solvable.

Comment: Interesting @Raskolnikov. Is there a simple example of $X$ being multivariate lognormal without $(\log X_1, ..., \log X_n)$ being multivariate normal?

Comment: @A rural reader: I suggest you read my reply again.